# Android - поднимать view (или активити) при выдвижении клавиатуры.

Tags: android, activity, view

Имеется прозрачная активити с виев стиля Theme.Translucent, посередине окошко LinearLayout, далее EditText. При выдвижении , клавиатура частично перекрывает окно. 
Как поднимать view при выдвижении клавиатуры.

Comment: Если все вставить в ScrollView, то будет подниматься.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) 
или

```
@android:style/Theme.Dialog
```

---

p.s. view [vju:]